# What songs share (variations of) the "As I Walked Down the Street" melody?

Tags: identify-this-song, melody

I was recently listening to a list of PBS Kids intersticials on YouTube, and I found a song called [As I Walked Down the Street](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hmr5tJ0HWQQ) and the melody of it reminded me of a few different possibilities.

- A song about buckle my shoe.
- A song about clap your hands.
- A Christmas song about early in the morning.

Comment: Are you asking about nursery rhymes that already share that melody (in the manner of  "Twinkle Twinkle Little Star" and the "ABC Song") or about hypothetical songs that could be created from this melody?

Comment: I'm asking about nursery rhymes that were already created and share that melody, like Twinkle Twinkle and ABC.

Answer (score 1):

What strikes me as most distinctive here is not the melody, but the structure, with the second half of the line repeated three times in total, and then a refrain. And the song that reminds me of is "This is the Way We Brush Our Teeth":

It's also the structure for "The Wheels on the Bus"

Comment: Here's the other song I was talking about. If you listen to the first part of it, it has similar structure. I don't know what song that is, though. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIhs9qUaZx4

Comment: If your main question is to identify what songs are in that clip, you should make that a separate question. It's a medley, so there are many different songs included. The first really clear one is "I Saw Three Ships Coming In" which does indeed have the lyric "in the morning".

Comment: @HeavenlyHarmony not only does _I Saw Three Ships_ have "in the morning," but it has a nearly if not quite identical melody.  Or, more precisely, it's the same melody translated (for want of a better term) to another part of the scale, and with minor variations in detail.  The song you link to in the question avoids discriminating against night owls by using "hi ho, hi ho, hi ho" instead.  I've definitely heard another song that uses the "walked down the street" variant, but I can't call it to mind just now.  If I do, I'll post an answer.